# What is $g$ for which this is true!

Tags: indefinite-integrals

For what $g\equiv g(r,q)$ such that following is true:
$$
\int_0^\infty r^{2n-1}g(r,q)dr=\frac{\Gamma(qn+1)}{n^2}.
$$
The function $g$ should be independent of $n$. It can only have $r$ and $q$.

Comment: What is the context for this problem?  What have you tried to solve it?

Comment: We individually know the structure of $g$ to get $\Gamma(qn+1)$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}$. But I am trying to combine this in the above format.

Comment: But what makes you think there is such a $g$ to begin with?  Is this a homework problem? An exercise in a book? Your own conjecture? Have you made partial progress? Where are you running into difficulties?